# Node js JSON: Access Object

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object

I parse 'body' and save it to my var jsonNew getting 'results'.

```
let json = JSON.parse(body);

var jsonNew = json['results'];
```

`jsonNew` gives me:

```
[
  {
    address_components: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    formatted_address: 'Germany',
    geometry: {
      location: [Object],
      location_type: 'ROOFTOP',
      viewport: [Object]
    },
    place_id: '123',
    plus_code: {
      compound_code: '123',
      global_code: '132+86'
    },
    types: [ 'street_address' ]
  }
]
```

How can I access geometry.location to get 'lat' and 'lng'?

Which are the search terms I need to google to find the solution? What exactly do I have here?

```
"geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 1234,
               "lng" : 12345
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 5555,
                  "lng" : 6666
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 555,
                  "lng" : 666
               }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this getting [0] of the array - I am stupid!

var jsonNew = json['results'][0].geometry.location;